# Creating a SQL view based on IDs shared between tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL, and I'm pretty bad at joins and select-from-select statements. One of my tables looks like this:

```
|id   | label  |
|123  | "foo"  |
|456  | "bar"  |
|789  | "baz"  |
```

and the other one looks like this:

```
|id   | tag  |
|123  | 456  |
|123  | 789  |
|456  | 789  |
```

I want a view--performance isn't particularly important--that looks like this:

```
| id   | label  |    tags   |
| 123  | "foo"  | "bar,baz" |
| 456  | "bar"  |   "baz"   |
```

How can I accomplish this? I'm aware of inner joins and the group_concat operator, but I don't know exactly how to replace the IDs with the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky because you need an aggregation as well as a couple of `join`s:

```
select t1.id, t1.label, group_concat(tt1.label) as tags
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id join
     t1 tt1
     on t2.tag = tt1.id
group by t1.id, t1.label
```

Comment: Incase he wants distinct or ordered tags in the returned set. Look up [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: I probably wouldn't have figured this out on my own. Thank you so much!